# Objective-C nil Outlets

Tags: objective-c, null, iboutlet

I have a class used for a user interface, with two constructors:

```
- (id)initWithBanner:(NSMutableArray *)banner {  
    if ( ( self = [super initWithNibName:@"UIBanner" bundle:nil] ) ) {
      // ... code...
    }
    return self;
}

- (id)initWithPreview:(NSMutableArray *)previews {
    if ( ( self = [super initWithNibName:@"UIBanner" bundle:nil] ) ) {
      // ... code...
    }
    return self;
}
```

Inside this two constructors, I use two outlets, a UIPageControl and a UIScrollView, linked with the new XCode 4. Now, if I use the first constructor, initWithBanner, everything works fine (putting a NSLog(@"%@",bannerScroll) gives the relative outlet description) but when I use initWithPreview, my Outlets are nil.
What's wrong with that?

Comment: As far as i can tell the two init methods are identical, so nothing* is wrong with the code you've posted.

Comment: It would seem that in the left out "... code ..." area, you might do something that is different between the two cases. Just guessing, otherwise, what we can see, is identical.

Comment: * Actually, and this is not the problem you're seeing, but one of these methods should be the designated initializer. http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocAllocInit.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH22-SW8

Comment: @Daniel Schneller: The code area are about the intializations and processing of iVars that are not labelled as IBOutlet connected to the Nib. i.g.: a UIView used to add the scroll content.

Comment: Where are the inits being called from? And on what object? If the outlets are linked in one case and not the other, it suggests they are not actually the same object, or at least not at the same point in its lifecycle.

Comment: @walkytalky: What do you mean with "if the outlets are linked in one case and not in the other"? In the class that uses the object with those methods there are two iVars called: UIBanner *previews and UIBanner *videos. The latter is initialized in a method using: videos = [[UIBanner alloc] initWithBanner:[self caricaVistine]]; and it works fine. The first is initialized in another method with: previews = [[UIBanner alloc] initWithPreview:anteprimaDati]; both methods are called correctly, with right data.

Comment: I mean whether the pointers are filled in with values loaded from the nib or are nil. (See Darren's answer, which is clearer than my comment.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your outlets will not be set until the nib is actually loaded, which occurs when your UIViewController's `view` property is read.  You implement the `-viewDidLoad` method to handle when your nib has loaded.  Also note that the view and nib can be unloaded and loaded multiple times during the life of your UIViewContoller instance.

Comment: This is driving me crazy. Using "self = [super initWithNibName:@"UIBanenr" bundle:nil]" should initialize the nibs, right?

Comment: Well, not happy of this behaviour, I've made a test. I've added a String to the class. In initWithBanner I've initialized it to "banner", in initWithPreview "preview". Also, I've put a NSLog inside the two constructors let's say "foo". I should see: "foo" "preview" "foo" "banner" or "foo" "banner" "foo" "preview", depending on what method is called at first, right? Well I see "foo" "preview" "(null)" "foo" wich means that my second viewDidLoad is called BEFORE the object is initialized... how should I handle this behaviour?