# viewDidLoad called Before Constructor

Tags: ios4, constructor, memory-management, viewdidload

This question is related to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5309759/objective-c-nil-outlets). I have two constructors:

```
- (id)initWithBanner:(NSMutableArray *)banners {
  if ( self = [super initWithNibName:@"UIBanner" bundle:nil] ) {
     testString = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"Banner"];
     NSLog(@"Foo");
  }

  return self;
}

- (id)initWithPreview:(NSMutableArray *)previews {
  if ( self = [super initWithNibName:@"UIBanner" bundle:nil];
    testString = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"Preview"];
    NSLog(@"Foo");
  }

  return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
  NSLog(@"%@", testString);
}
```

In another object I have two instances of this class called *bannerPreview and *bannerVideo, initialized with initWithPreview and initWithVideo. Here what it happens:
In the preview constructor, I can't access to IBOutlets, because they are nil, while they are not in the banner. But the method viewDidLoad of bannerVideo gets called BEFORE the constructor has finished, while the viewDidLoad of bannerPreview does not. I've added a string test in the class, and a NSLog(@"Foo") in the two methods listed above and my output is:

```
2011-03-15 12:29:13.929 iUDC[2600:207] Foo
2011-03-15 12:29:13.934 iUDC[2600:207] preview
2011-03-15 12:29:15.038 iUDC[2600:207] (null)
2011-03-15 12:29:15.038 iUDC[2600:207] Foo
```

How should I handle this behaviour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you do in your `init` should be independent of what you do in `viewDidLoad`. Anything that is dependent on `self.view` should be done in `viewDidLoad`.

Whether `viewDidLoad` is called before or after the `init` has finished is dependent on how long it takes to load the view and how long it takes to execute the `init`.

Comment: So... If I have to make some initializing processing that requires I should only gives the start up in the constructor. Right? And What about the Outlets? Aren't they initialized from [super initWithNibName: bundle:]?

Answer (score 0):

You've got a bug in your `initWithPreview:` method. It should probably say:

```
[super initWithNibName:@"UIPreview" bundle:nil]
```